# Safari multiple properties in keyframe animations

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

Trying to animate multiple properties in safari in an animation doesn't seem to work.

```
@keyframes move
  from
    filter drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px red)
    transform rotateX(15deg) translateY(-1rem)
  to
    filter drop-shadow(0 -5px 50px green)
    transform translateY(2rem) rotateX(-15deg)
```

Here's an example of something that works perfectly in chrome:

https://jsbin.com/zoyarokuge/1/edit?html,css,output

Doesn't work at all in safari. Animation each property, transform or filter individually works fine though. Is this a known bug, are there workarounds?

Comment: define two animation and apply them both, maybe it will work

Answer (score -1):

Different browsers will have different vendor prefixes. For example for google chrome and safari use -webkit and internet explorer we need to use -ms. For your query you can use, in place of @keyframes you can use @-webkit-keyframes and instead of animation you can use -webkit-animation.